# REGEX - specify groups, grouping order

Tags: regex, backreference, regex-group

When I write regex as follows:

```
/(.*)/(.*)
```

from string

```
/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

I get groups:

```
#1  aaa/bbb
#2  ccc
```

But I would like it to be like:

```
#1  aaa
#2  bbb/ccc
```

How can I change grouping order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways to achieve this:

1. Lazy Matching - like [`/(.*?)/(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/hpPZsk/1)

`.*` matches greedy, so the first `.*` first matches as much as possible (= the reminder of the string), then backtracks until the forward slash can be matched. Lazy matching works the other way around, `.*?` matches as few as possible (= nothing) and then expands until the slash can be matched.

2. Negative character class matching - like [`/([^/]*)/(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/hpPZsk/2)

As we know, that we want to match everything before the forward slash, we can use a character class where the forward slash is negated and then match greedy again. This is more performant as you can match in one step, instead expanding your pattern with lazy matching.